# How to consume same React context coming from different packages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to consume same React context coming from different packages?

E.g. I have `package A` which depends on `common` and `common` deps on `ui-lib`, and `packageA` deps on `ui-lib`.

In `ui-lib` there is an `export const context = React.createContext({..})`
and in `package A` and in `common` it will be different instances of the same context (because of different packages during the build).

I have few options now but they all.. not so good:

**Solution A**:  re-export all the stuff from `ui-lib` in `common`, and in `packageA` import only from `common`

**Solution B**: use two context Providers in `package A` (one from `ui-lib` and one from `common`)

More context:

1. I'm using npm without package locks
2. I need this working while `package A` and `common` builds separately on CI
3. `package A` and `common` is inside monorepo and `ui-lib` is external package, so we have in our repo:

```
— packages
—— packageA (deps on `common` from same monorepo and `ui-lib` )
—— common (deps on `ui-lib`)
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

One of the options to solve this - you can extract a separate package only for the context provider. This new package would have a pretty stable version, which doesn't change often.

Your structure might look like this:

```
packageA
    common
        ui-lib@2.0.0
          context-provider-package@1.0.0
    ui-lib@1.0.0
      context-provider-package@1.0.0
```

so the context will be the same. But this approach still has a risk to break the React Context eventually by updating one of the `context-provider-package` versions

Answer (score 0):

If there are two different instances of the same package, then this package is duplicated in the resulting bundle, that is not good.

- Check `ui-lib` versions should be the same
- Check hoisting and package linking at dev. env